# How to convert Exist data from nvarchar to float in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Overseas` in SQL Server take its data from an Excel sheet so numbers data sometimes is converted to text. I want to perform an analysis so I have to convert this text to float each time I load this Excel file.

I created another table with datatype `float` to copy the same table data to make analysis easier.

I tried this command; it works but the existing data doesn't get changed

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([SalesValue],',','') )[SalesValue]
FROM 
    Overseas
```

sql table

[image]

For example : `SalesValue` column is `nvarchar` i want to convert it to `float` and the data existing converted from `nvarchar` to `float` .. i want the output like this

[image]

Any help or another easier way ?

Comment: any sample data ?

Comment: If you want to **update** the data in the table, you must use an `UPDATE`  statement - not just a `SELECT` ....

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert' when i used update

Comment: GuidoG .. i post sql table

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of pictures.

Comment: jarlh what do u mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to change the row from design to float

Answer (score 1):

Try below query : Use CAST method ,

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE([SalesValue],',','') AS Float )[SalesValue]
FROM Overseas
```

Comment: old data still have , and still nvarchar

Comment: @AmrKamal,Post your sample data and expected output.

Comment: I don't understand what do u mean with sample data ? sorry

Comment: @AmrKamal,What existing value you have and which type conversion you need.Post both data then only we understand what you expected.